# LINQ Select within List of custom type?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using SparkPost on my application to send emails to me and clients. In order to do this, I need to serialize an array using C#. I have the following code that does not seem to be working and I have no idea why.

```
recipients = new List<Recipient>() {
    toAddresses.Select(addr => new Recipient() {
        address = addr.ToString()
    })
}
```

`toAddresses` is just a `List<string>` with email addresses.

Recipient class:

```
class Recipient {
    public string address;
}
```

The output of that LINQ select should look like this:

```
recipients = new List<Recipient>(){
    new Recipient() {
        address ="joe_scotto@1.net"
    },
    new Recipient() {
        address ="joe_scotto@2.net"
    },
    new Recipient() {
        address ="joe_scotto@1.net"
    },
    new Recipient() {
        address ="jscotto@2.com"
    }
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Specific Errors:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'app.Recipient'
>
> Error  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List.Add(Recipient)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments

Request String:

```
wc.UploadString("https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
new {
    options = new {
        ip_pool = "sa_shared"
    },
    content = new {
        from = new {
            name = "a Sports",
            email = "no-reply@colorizer.a.com"
        },
        subject = subject,
        html = emailBody
    },
    recipients = new List<Recipient>() {
        toAddresses.Select(addr => new Recipient() {
            address => addr
        })
    }
}
```

));

Comment: Can you please describe in what way your current code "does not seem to be working?" Are you getting an error message? Different output than you'd expected?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior See updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you need simple mapping

```
var recipients = toAddresses.Select(addr => new Recipient { address = addr }).ToList();
```

You cannot use `IEnumerable` as parameter for list initialization

```
var recipients = new List<Recipient>() { toAddresses.Select...  }
```

Initialization logic will call `List.Add` on every item you pass in `{  }`, so it expects instances of `Recepient` separated by comma, but when you pass there `IEnumerable` it fail.

`List<T>` have overload constructor which accept `IEnumerable<T>` as argument so you can use this

```
var recepients = new List<Recepient>(toAddresses.Select(addr => new Recipient {address = addr}));
```

But on my own opinion simple mapping seems more readable.

```
var message = new 
{
    options = new 
    { 
        ip_pool = "sa_shared"
    },
    content = new 
    {
        from = new 
        {
            name = "a Sports",
            email = "no-reply@colorizer.a.com"
        },
        subject = subject,
        html = emailBody
    },
    recipients = toAddresses.Select(addr => new Recipient() { address = addr}).ToList()
}
```

Comment: Why would this work when his existing code doesn't work?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: because when the `List<Recipient>` constructor is invoked, the compiler expects the LINQ query to result in a *single* recipient. It gives an error: `Argument `#1' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Recipient>' expression to type `Recipient'`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think the point was that the reason should be part of the answer.

Comment: Good edit. You may also want to mention that he could have passed the `Select` result into the *constructor* of the `new List<Recipient()`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, why do you think it makes sense to pass `Select` to `ctor`?

Comment: How could I use this though in my request string? See my updated question.

Comment: `Error CS1922 Cannot initialize type 'Recipient' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`

Comment: Change `...new Recipient() { address => addr} ..` to `...new Recipient() { address = addr} ..` - do not copy paste code :)

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov: I only said that because I think that's what the OP probably thought he was doing. The fact that he was `new`ing up a List and trying to pass values through the initializer makes me think he'd seen a similar approach before (using the constructor argument) and was just getting confused between the two syntaxes. Fabio did a great job with this answer.